# Use of IF function in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am running a short `if` function in R but am getting the following warning message:

```
In if ((runif(50, 0, 1) < 0.69)) { :  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`.
```

My rudimentary grasp of R leads me to believe that `runif` generates a vector but `if` yields a single value, so I'm thinking this is the issue. Is there any simple substitution for if here?

Also i want the end product to be a matrix combination of the two arguments but i wasn't sure if it was correct to put 50 in the `rnorm` function for both scenarios.

```
Test <-
 if((runif(50, 0, 1)<0.69)) {
 rnorm(50, 25, 4)
 } else {
 rnorm(50, 28, 4.3)
}
```

Comment: What do you want to get at the end ? A vector of 50 items ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`if()` expects whetever is in the parentheses to evaluate to a logical vector of length 1 (`TRUE` or `FALSE`). If the vector is longer than 1, then as the warning says only the first element of the vector is used.

An alternative if `ifelse()` where it is used as :

```
ifelse(test, TRUE_CASE, FALSE_CASE)
```

For your example we have:

```
set.seed(1)
ifelse(runif(50, 0, 1) < 0.69, rnorm(50, 25, 4), rnorm(50, 28, 4.3))
```

or

```
set.seed(1)
test <- runif(50, 0, 1)
Tcase <- rnorm(50, 25, 4)
Fcase <- rnorm(50, 28, 4.3)
ifelse(test, Tcase, Fcase)
```

Either is OK as `ifelse()` generates the two vectors for `TRUE_CASE` and `FALSE_CASE` before doing the comparisons.

Example output is:

```
R> ifelse(test < 0.69, Tcase, Fcase)
 [1] 24.77549 24.37682 19.11699 28.31967 26.67177 25.55472 27.41873 26.55069
 [9] 24.78478 19.49176 23.34002 23.42284 24.76275 29.40010 29.14852 24.34191
[17] 33.19383 32.98973 27.22665 34.82338 30.40149 26.45833 28.07413 24.55062
[25] 28.52443 26.59242 22.55189 26.36448 28.67952 30.73209 32.92160 23.53111
[33] 20.82346 27.27888 35.23336 34.60647 26.01493 27.75896 25.20201 22.02691
[41] 26.31093 17.78017 26.79981 25.61301 33.69045 25.82438 22.16021 27.44291
[49] 27.22791 27.56918
```

Another way is to do this is to only generate the required values

```
want <- test < 0.69
res <- test ## copy vector of correct length
res[want] <- rnorm(S <- sum(want), 25, 4)
res[!want] <- rnorm(length(res) - S, 28, 4.3)

R> res
 [1] 27.85067 24.70574 24.84946 22.04696 22.27336 36.03795 29.82793 23.70292
 [9] 25.24064 22.64442 27.12598 18.92642 26.22623 18.85420 26.97382 23.79610
[17] 32.55148 31.81162 22.88688 25.33725 37.48624 22.39162 24.77241 17.34256
[25] 29.70633 18.34011 23.14588 20.53632 26.90338 21.99672 33.34867 25.06958
[33] 19.85480 18.43758 21.87467 26.80075 27.37908 24.92576 28.89241 23.72773
[41] 37.92431 21.28255 28.45495 19.05016 20.69923 29.96509 29.00012 22.51493
[49] 27.66824 26.56380
```

That obviously gives different numbers to the previous ones but only because we generated fewer random numbers. I doubt this will be any more efficient than `ifelse()` for most problems.

Comment: Excellent, Thank you. I had just stumbled across ifelse

Comment: @ Gavin Just for complete clarification of what ifelse is doing: taking the first of the 50 random numbers generated between 0 and 1 using runif, if this value is less than 0.69, then a value is generated from the normal distribution (50, 25, 4) and if it is greater, then a value is generated from (50, 28, 4.3). Then the final output is simply an ammalgamation of the values into a list/matrix of 50 values. Is my summary correct for the procedure performed?

Comment: Yes, except for the last bit; the result is a numeric vector of 50 values. I've added an example of the output.

Comment: Saw another comment here a short while ago with a different method and asking for further clarification on the output required. Now is has dissappeared

Comment: Just as a learning aside, why is it necessary to specify 50 possible generatable values for both scenarios? is there a more concise way of doing this somehow, say by (1:50) as x and then specifying rnorm(x, 25, 4).  im just thinking out loud here really and seeking to learn a little bit. Thanks

Comment: The user that posted that Answer decided to delete their Answer. You don't have sufficient reputation to see deleted Answers.

Comment: It is more efficient to generate 50 values in a single go for each scenario than to have many calls to `rnorm()` determined on the basis of the clause. There are other ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks, i have made a small edit to the question to incorporate another minor issue i am having.

Comment: Please *don't* do things like that. SO isn't just a means for you to get Answers but is also a resource for other people who might come across similar issues. There is nothing wrong with starting a new Question, linking to this one for relevant detail. I'll take a look at the Edit later.

Answer (score 1):

You need `any` or `all`, which convert a vector of logicals into a single logical (well, actually a vector of length 1).